# Reqular Expression with pipe

Tags: regex

I have a string that will be used as a config value.. It is like `1|1|1` or `1|1|2` or `2|1|2` and so on. There are eight different combinations. Integers are either `1` or `2`..

The problem is that I have to use pipe between integers. In regex pipe means "or" but I need it in my string..

`[1-2][\|][1-2][\|][1-2]` is what I came up with. Is this logical or are there any better options?

Comment: It's fine. Except that you don't need to escape `|` in `character class`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use:

```
([12])\|([12])\|([12])
```

So you catch both 1 and 2 and have them in a group for future usage.

The minus sign is not nessesary, because there is no character possible in ASCII between `1` and `2`.